# How to handle events from a CheckedChangedListener in a ListView

Tags: android

Iv'e got a custom Listview implemented in this particular class, it looks like

[Image/Textview/Checkbox]

When someone clicks on the text is should launch another class, this is working at the moment, however when someone clicks a checkbox I want to update an array that stores the current state of all the checkboxes, I tried doing that via using a onCheckedChanged method within the custom adapter however it doesn't work as the position variable isn't final. So two questions

1 within the adapter is their a way to get the position of the Checkbox so I can change the right position in the array, and

2 If not is their another way to update the array somewhere else without disrupting the current functionality of the onClick.

Here is my onCheckedChanged within my adapter

```
CheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton but, boolean b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        if(but.isChecked())
        {
            deleteList[???] = true;
        }else{
            deleteList[???] = false;
        }
    }

   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look a this [method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29).  You can set a tag to a view containing any object you wish, which in your case may be the integer value associated with the CheckBox's row.

So when you create your CheckBox:

```
but.setTag(new Integer(position));
```

This would change your if statement to:

```
if (but.isChecked()){
    deleteList[((Integer) but.getTag()).intValue()] = true;
} else {
    deleteList[((Integer) but.getTag()).intValue()] = false;
}
```

Let me know if this helps!